# Randomizing images in image views

Tags: android

i wanted to make an application in which i have to randomaly generate images but in order....

like :- APPLE.... i want to generate it as   A_PP_E....
but i also want them uniqualy every time

```
final int[] imageViews = {
        R.id.imageView2, R.id.imageView10, R.id.imageView3, 
        R.id.imageView4, R.id.imageView5, R.id.imageView6, R.id.imageView8  };
int[] photos={R.drawable.aa, R.drawable.pp
        ,R.drawable.ee,
        R.drawable.pp_blue,R.drawable.ll};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // for randomizing the view
     Random rng = new Random(); 
     List<Integer> generated = new ArrayList<Integer>();
     for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
     {
       while(true)
       {
          Integer next = rng.nextInt(5) ;
          if (!generated.contains(next))
          {
             generated.add(next);
             ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(imageViews[i]);
             iv.setImageResource(photos[next]);
             break;
          }
        }
     }
```

Comment: it generate random images but not in a order

Comment: what is the problem with the current code?

Comment: iwant this kind of view A_PP_E(for apple) but i m getting PPL_ A

Comment: How many _ (dash/empty) you want every time? Or is that also random.. then sometime it will be all empty sometime all filled??

Comment: i want atleast 2 dash every time..but in random positions

Comment: Do you have image for _ or is it empty image view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1):** put the images in the array in correct order as follows:

```
int[] photos={R.drawable.aa, R.drawable.pp, R.drawable.pp_blue, R.drawable.ll, R.drawable.ee}; // correct order APPLE
```

**Step 2):** Update your code as below:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Random rng = new Random();
    List<Integer> generated = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    // select `n` places which will be "BLANK"
    int n = 2; // example `n=2`
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        while(true)
        {
            Integer next = rng.nextInt(5) ;
            if (!generated.contains(next))
            {
                generated.add(next);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // now `generated` has `n` random positions
    // set these `n` positions as "BLANK" rest as "FILLED"
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(imageViews[i]);
        if(generated.contains(i)) {
            // this was a random selected position
            // set it blank or empty
            iv.setImageBitmap(null);
        }
        else {
            // set this image as the correct alphabet
            iv.setImageResource(photos[i]);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Oh my mistake.. please remove the last `break` its there by mistake.. i think due to copy/paste.. updated my answer

Comment: now i have to put those missing images in another image view.....is their any way to get those......

Comment: that whould we appricialble..thaks n advance

Comment: You already know the position of missing images. It is inside the `generated` list. Loop through this list, do something like  `otherImageView.setImageResource(photos[generated.get(i)]);`

Comment: where do i have to do this inside generation of blank spases or start a new loop

Comment: Start a new loop is better. Please try to understand what is happening in the code above. You won't be able to do anything on your own otherwise. The questions you are asking are pretty basic showing that you don't know what is going on..

Comment: i understand whats in the code..... actully i m doing first time with random image view which always gives me the wrong output

Comment: Maybe we should talk else where as this is not a place for chatting or disscussions?

Comment: this is my gmail acoount "satyamaan@gmail.com" invite me in chat

Answer (score 0):

i m doing this for getting blank images in another image view array....and its giving correct output

```
int n = 2; // example `n=2`
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        while(true)
        {
            Integer next = rng.nextInt(5) ;
            Log.i("test","value:-"+next);               
            if (!generated.contains(next))
            {
                generated.add(next);
                break;
            }

        }
    }

    for (int i1 = 0; i1 < 2; i1++)
    {
        ImageView ne = (ImageView)findViewById(nextimages[i1]);

         ne.setImageResource(photos[generated.get(i1)]);Log.i("test","value:-"+photos[generated.get(i1)]);
    }
```